# Eclipse Subversive revision numbers on multiple project commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, numbers, revision, subversive

If I have 2 projects in Eclipse that refers to the same repository location.

> repository location: svn://server
>   project-module1 ->
>   svn://server/trunk/project-module1
>   project-module2 ->
>   svn://server/trunk/project-module2

So if I sync the project change with Subversive and have a change in module1 and module2 that refers to the same context I select all files and perform one commit, but if I look into my project revisions after that I see that 2 revisions were created. One for module1 and one for module2 with the same comment.

How can I change the behave that only one revision number is created?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the command line version of Subversion installed?

What's the output when you do:

```
$ svn log --verbose svn://server/trunk
```

This will give you a better idea what's happening.

If both modules are considered separate Eclipse projects and each has their own separate checkout, Eclipse will create separate commits for both of them. Is this the case?